# Embed facebook send message dialog box?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to embed the send message dialog box for facebook in a webpage so that the dialog box does not open up? Right now, on button click, it opens a dialog.

Thanks so much for all your help!

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    window.inviteFriends = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '{{facebookAppId}}',
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.0'
        });                 
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'send',
                        link: 'site name',
                        display: 'dialog',
                        app_id: '{{facebookAppId}}'
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        if (response) {
                           startLoading();
                        } else {
                            console.log("NOTCLICKED");
                        }
                    }); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. And there are no workarounds.